# Rcpp function with no argument

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I am developing a R package using Rcpp, and now I an trying to include the following c++ function without input arguments:

```
int printVariables() {
    // Code
    return 0;
}
```

I have in my `RcppExports.cpp` the next function:

```
int printVariables();
RcppExport SEXP printVariables() {
BEGIN_RCPP
    Rcpp::RObject __result;
    Rcpp::RNGScope __rngScope;
    __result = Rcpp::wrap(printVariables());
    return __result;
END_RCPP
}
```

Finally, in the RcppExports.R I have an entry as follows:

```
printVariables <- function() {
    .Call('printVariables', PACKAGE = 'my_package')
}
```

When I compile the code I get this error:

```
RcppExports.cpp: In function ‘SEXPREC* printVariables()’:
RcppExports.cpp:54:37: error: ambiguating new declaration of ‘SEXPREC* printVariables()’
 RcppExport SEXP printVariables() {
RcppExports.cpp:53:5: note: old declaration ‘int printVariables()’
 int printVariables();
```

Anyone knows how can I solve that issue?

Comment: Of what type is `RcppExport`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just place an ignored argument there.  Return type `void` works, but you *must* have at least a single argument you are free to ignore.

```
R> cppFunction("void foo(int ignored=0) { double d; }")
R> foo()
R>
```

See the [Rcpp Attributes vignette](https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-attributes.pdf) for all the glorious details.

*Edit* I do stand corrected, thanks to @hrbrmstr, who correctly points out that this *does of course* work  in a package.  I.e. even the sample function created by RStudio when asked to do File -> New Project -> New Directory -> R Package, and when 'Package w/ Rcpp' is select has this:

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
List rcpp_hello() {
  CharacterVector x = CharacterVector::create("foo", "bar");
  NumericVector y   = NumericVector::create(0.0, 1.0);
  List z            = List::create(x, y);
  return z;
}
```

which is evidently *sans* argument.

Comment: rly? (i hate asking that, too, given who this answer is by :-) I literally just added the OP's function to a test rcpp package I have for this stuff  but used the `// [[Rcpp::export]]` helper to generate the other bits and it worked fine w/o a dummy argument. Might not it be that they have `int printVariables();` in a header file that's clobbering the one in the exports cpp?

Comment: Maybe it works in a package and OP _just_ forgot to add `// [[Rcpp::exports]]` -- that also rhymes with what I recall....  For `cppFunction()` use, though, you do need a dummy arg.  And in general it i) won;t hurt and ii) who _really_ cares?

Comment: It works with the dummy argument. In the same way, I supose functions must return something, being impossible a void-returning function, isn't it?

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel both of these lines work fine: 1. `Rcpp::cppFunction("void foo() { int i = 1 + 1; }")` and 2. `Rcpp::cppFunction("int foo2() { int i = 1 + 1; return i; }")`. Similarly for using `Rcpp::sourceCpp()`. I'm betting that it is indeed the `// [[Rcpp::exports]]` line that is mia.

Comment: @bra_racing: Re-read my answer. It contains a function returning `void` so that does work.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Yes I had just read it, I am looking for the way to implement it in my `RcppExports.cpp`, I think `VOID_END_RCPP` is the key, I continue investigating ;)

Comment: Do. Not. Write. Those. By. Hand.

Comment: I have a file with the cpp functions, a file .R with a .Call() for each function and a `RcppExports.cpp` which is like a 'bridge' between both, and I edit all of them when I add a new function. Isn't it correct?

Comment: Please see the vignette Rcpp Attributes.  Please maybe try starting a package from scratch in RStudio (or call `compileAttributes()` by hand).  You appear to be doing it wrong, and I cannot coach you via interspersed three-lines messages.

Comment: Ok, I'll study that document. I follow that structure because is which is created with the Rcpp.package.skeleton. Thank you very much for your useful answers

Comment: Point taken -- `Rcpp.package.skeleton()` ships those files and does not make it all that clear which ones are to be human-edited.  In short, *never ever* touch `RcppExports.R` and `RcppExports.cpp` yourself.  They have comments at the top saying so.

Comment: But, that simplifies it a lot! The Rcpp::compileAttributes make that work itself!! Every day I love Rcpp more than the day before ;)

Comment: Yay!! Some good news at last!!  If you have suggestions for making it clearer that you're not supposed to edit RcppExports.{cpp,R} I'd be all ear. Do file an issue ticket...

Comment: It's clear enough, my problem was I didn't know what the compileAttributes do